# Returning data on page based on url query params

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am using `Next.js` Here is my file structure:

```
--courses  (folder)
 -course.js  (file)
  --chapters   (folder)
    -[chapter].js   (file)
```

I have a chapter called "hello-world" which will be in [chapter].js

I want the route to be as follows:

**<Link href={"/courses/chapters/hello-world?section=10"}>Hello World</Link>**

I want the `[chapter].js` file to be used by multiple `pages/components`.
In the `[chapter].js` file, when I say:

```
const router = useRouter();

console.log("router params: ", router.query);
```

I get the following: `hello-world`

I do not get section = 10

I want to be able to get the `hello-world` page that will be served from [chapter].js and also get the section=10 URL param.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var router = useRouter();
var section = router.query["section"];
```